# UISearchBar misses elements in the non-visible part of the tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a TableView with many rows, most are not visible at the time of loading viewController. The rows of UITableView are extracted from a SQLite database. How can I make do that the SearchBar search between all rows and not just the visible ones?

In header file:

```
 @interface ExhibitorsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>{
BOOL isSearchOn;
BOOL canSelectRow;
NSMutableArray * listOfExpositors;
NSMutableArray * searchResult;

}

 //....
 @end
```

In implementation file

```
 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     if(isSearchOn){
           return [searchResult count];
           //In this array there are the elements after use of searchBar
     }else{
          int number=[self.mutableArray count];
         //In this array there are all elements of database, extracts in viewDidLoad()
       return number;
     }
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         if (cell == nil) {
           cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
           reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
}

       if(isSearchOn){
            NSString * cellValue = [searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
      }else{
           //loading data from the database
           Database *currow =[self.mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

           cell.textLabel.text = currow.name;


         [listOfExpositors addObject:cell.textLabel.text];
         //here only loads the list of names visible and not the entire table
         //How do I put all the elements in this array?
         NSLog(@" %@", listOfExpositors);

         isSearchOn = NO;
         canSelectRow = YES;
  }
}




 -(void) doneSearching{
      isSearchOn = NO;
      canSelectRow = YES;
      self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;

     [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
     [self.tableView reloadData];

 }

  -(void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
        isSearchOn = YES;
        if(self.searchBar.text.length>0){
            canSelectRow=YES;
            self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        }else{
            canSelectRow= NO;
            self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

        }
    }

   -(void) searchExpositorsTableView{
         [searchResult removeAllObjects];

         for (NSString *str in listOfExpositors){


              NSRange titleResultsRange = [str rangeOfString:self.searchBar.text options:
               NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];;

              if (titleResultsRange.length >0) {
                      [searchResult addObject:str];

              }
          }
        NSLog(@"%@", searchResult);
      }

    -(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
             if([searchText length]>0){
                     canSelectRow = YES;
                     self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
                     [self searchExpositorsTableView];
             }else{
                    canSelectRow = NO;
                    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;


              }

             [self.tableView reloadData];
        }

      -(void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
            [self searchExpositorsTableView];
            [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
      }

   -(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        if(canSelectRow){


            return indexPath;

        }else{
              return nil;
       }
      NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);
    }
```

Comment: can you show your code for numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Did you mean that the items in your tableview is from SQLite db? I suggest that you get the items from the db and store it in an array... Then let your tableView refer to the array where you've stored the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was wrong to use the array created in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** because it was limited only to the visible elements. I then used the NSMutableArray created in viewDidLoad () that does contain all the elements of the database. I changed the following methods:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //....

   if(isSearchOn){
       NSString * cellValue = [searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
   }else{
      Database *currow =[self.mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


       cell.textLabel.text = currow.name;

     //Should be removed  this array and used to another, self.mutableArray

    //[listOfExpositors addObject:cell.textLabel.text];
    // NSLog(@" %@", listOfExpositors);

    isSearchOn = NO;
    canSelectRow = YES;
  }
}
```

Method for research

```
 -(void) searchExpositorsTableView{
      [searchResult removeAllObjects];

      for (Database *currow in self.mutableArray){ 
             /*In self.mutableArray there are all elements because is created in
               viewDidLoad*/
             NSLog(@"list of expositors %@", self.mutableArray);

             NSRange titleResultsRange = [currow.name rangeOfString:self.searchBar.text options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
             if (titleResultsRange.length >0) {
                  [searchResult addObject:currow.name];

             }
        }

       NSLog(@"%@", searchResult);
     }
```